# How to promulgate a list of arguments for a python function?

Tags: python, optional-arguments, keyword-argument

I am trying to find an elegant pythonic way to solve the following problem. I have a class, `VideoAnalysisWidget`, that creates a whole bunch of child widgets such as `VideoFileChoiceWidget`, `RegionWidget`, etc. I want `VideoAnalysisWidget.__init__` to pass any appropriate keyword arguments to `VideoFileChoiceWidget.__init__`, `RegionWidget.__init__`, ... To accomplish this, I would like to use code like the following:

```
import inspect

def filterArgs(func, **kwargs):
    spec = inspect.getargspec(func)
    ks = set(kwargs.keys())
    ks.discard('self')
    kinc = ks & set(spec.args)
    kexc = ks - set(spec.args)
    inc = {k: kwargs[k] for k in kinc}
    exc = {k: kwargs[k] for k in kexc}
    return(inc, exc)
```

Then, elsewhere:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    (fcwArgs, otherArgs) = filterArgs(VideoFileChoiceWidget.__init__, **kwargs)
    fcw = VideoFileChoiceWidget(**fcwArgs)
    ...
```

Doing things this way, my code for `VideoAnalysisWidget` doesn't have to keep track of the argument list of `VideoFileChoiceWidget`. If I later revise `VideoFileChoiceWidget` to take a new argument, I don't need to make changes in the distant `VideoAnalysisWidget` code.

Now here's the problem. This works fine if `VideoFileChoiceWidget` has only explicitly defined keyword parameters. (BTW, I'm fine with not using any positional parameters other than `self` for any of these functions.) But what if `VideoFileChoiceWidget` also has a `**kwargs` argument? It does, in fact, because it's subclassed from `ContainerWidget`, so I want to pass any extra extra arguments on to that. (And `ContainerWidget` takes ONLY `**kwargs`.) Fundamentally, the problem is that this solution of mine can't be nested.

A possible solution would be to attach a list of additional arguments to `VideoFileChoiceWidget.__init__`, e.g.:

```
VideoFileChoiceWidget.__init__._args = ['description', 'visible', 'children']
```

...then modify `filterArgs` to use this if available. But is there a better, more pythonic way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best way, due to use of `inspect`, but in these cases usually I group the lot of kwargs into a class and pass that around.

Comment: Yes, I can see that as a solution. The argument against it (which may not be a GOOD argument) is that it essentially rebuilds the built-in KW arg-passing functions in user code, making everything less transparent.

Comment: Heres my take: when arguments are shared and too big for child classes to manage, as you said in your case, might as well do it for separation of concerns. It's actually done fairly often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going ahead with a variant on the approach I outlined in my original post, in which I attach an attribute to `__init__`. However, instead of making it a list, I am taking the more flexible approach of using a function. I define an unattached function `argNames` that takes one or more classes or functions as arguments and returns a set of argument names, using `inspect` and, recursively, calls to the `argNames` attribute of the functions. I can then attach this to `VideoFileChoiceWidget.__init__` (for instance), using:

```
class VideoFileChoiceWidget(ContainerWidget):
    ...<stuff>...
    def __init__(arg1, arg2, ..., **kwargs):
        ...<more stuff>...

    __init__.argNames = lambda: (argNames(ContainerWidget) | 
                                 {'description', 'visible', 'children'})
```

Anyone who wants to pass arguments on to `VideoFileChoiceWidget` uses `filterArgs` as outlined in the question. I have implemented this and it seems to work.

Below, for reference, are my current definitions of `argNames` and `filterArgs`.

```
def argNames(*args):
    """
    Get the names of the argument for a function

    Returns:
    --------
    A set whose members are the argument names

    Parameters:
    -----------
    func1, func2, ... -- the functions to be analyzed. The arguments
        are discovered by inspecting func. In addition, if
        func.argNames is defined, it is called (without arguments) to
        get a list of addition names. Any number of functions may be
        listed. If func is a class, func.__init__ is used
        instead. 'self' is always removed from the argument list.
    """
    names = set({})
    for a in args:
        try:
            func = a
            spec = inspect.getargspec(func)
        except TypeError:
            func = a.__init__
            spec = inspect.getargspec(func)
        names |= set(spec.args)
        try:
            names |= set(func.argNames())
        except AttributeError:
            pass
    names.discard('self')
    return(names)

def filterArgs(func, **kwargs):
    """
    Select keyword arguments for a function
    """
    args = argNames(func)
    ks = set(kwargs.keys())
    ks.discard('self')
    kinc = ks & args
    kexc = ks - args
    inc = {k: kwargs[k] for k in kinc}
    exc = {k: kwargs[k] for k in kexc}
    return(inc, exc)
```